# Would INNER JOIN on equality of two keys delete rows effectively?

Tags: query-performance, join, primary-key, delete

Ī̲ repair a MediaWiki site after a DoS attack which injected terabytes of garbage into the `text` table. Ī̲ found that `DELETE` with clauses works painfully slow and, even worse, locks the table; that is, the site cannot be edited during the process. Ī̲ circumvent the lock with

```
INSERT INTO text_garbage SELECT old_id FROM text WHERE old_text LIKE ⋯;
```

(note that actual queries have more details, which are not relevant here).

Now Ī̲ plan to use

```
DELETE FROM text INNER JOIN text_garbage ON text.old_id = text_garbage.old_id;
```

to actually delete the garbage.
Should such `DELETE` run significantly faster than direct `DELETE FROM text WHERE`⋯ queries?

Comment: Assuming that it is joined on the clustered index it can be faster. Still advice to to the delete in chunks to prevent your table locking problem

Comment: @Peter mean `old_id BETWEEN` *min* `AND` *max*? Surely Ī̲ know how to replace one long lock with a score of short ones, but the locked table will not be writable anyway, will it?

Comment: If there is no lock escalation, only the rows/pages affecting are not writeable then.

Comment: Min max, but batches from around 2,3k each